# Entity framework metadata exception - No csdl, ssdl, msl in dll resources

Tags: entity-framework, resources, metadata, edmx

I have DAL (model first entity framework 4.1) and Service  which is using it in separate projects. Everything was working fine, but after some minor changes (for example I generated model from database) it stoppedd working. I am now getting metadata exception.
After many hours of research I downloaded ILSpy and checked that inside DAL.dll there are no resources.
My connection string looks like:

```
metadata=res://*/DataModel.TerminalRegistryModel.csdl|
         res://*/DataModel.TerminalRegistryModel.ssdl|
         res://*/DataModel.TerminalRegistryModel.msl;
```

ANd in EDMX file metadata artifact processing is set to Embed in Output Assembly.
What can cause my problem?

Comment: I have recently run into this problem. In my solution, local builds have the metadata resources embedded. But in automated builds, the resources are missing.

Answer (score 3):

The standard metadata string looks like this:
`metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl`
And this works fine in most cases. However, in some Entity Framework get confused and does not know which dll to look in. Therefore, change the metadata string to:
`metadata=res://nameOfDll/Model.csdl|res://nameOfDll/Model.ssdl|res://nameOfDll/Model.msl`

Comment: Do you need to include the ".dll" extension in "nameOfDll"?

Comment: @PeterX Yes,you need to include full name of assembly.