# Entity Framework MySql: Argument 'xmlReader' not valid

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to use Entity Framework for with MySql with dynamic connection string, i.e. connection string is determined at runtime.

I included Entity Framework and EF MySql via NuGet.

I build my Model Code First from existing database.

I extended the Model to work with a connection string and added a static method to generate the connection string:

```
public partial class Model1
{
    public Model1(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }

    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var sqlCsBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlCsBuilder.Server = "myhost";
        sqlCsBuilder.UserID = "myuser";
        sqlCsBuilder.Password = "mypass";
        sqlCsBuilder.Database = "mydb";

        var connectionString = sqlCsBuilder.ToString();

        var entityConnectionStringBuilder= new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = connectionString;
        entityConnectionStringBuilder.Metadata = "res://*";

        var entityConnectionString = entityConnectionStringBuilder.ToString();

        return entityConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Initiating connection seems to work, or at least does not throw any errors, but it throws when trying the first read operation:

```
using (var db = new Model1(Model1.GetConnectionString()))
{
    var items = db.mytable.Where(i => i.ID < 1000);
}
```

Instantiating the Model1 object works, but the .Where causes an exception:

```
Additional information: Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid.
A minimum of one .ssdl artifact must be supplied.
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effort Unit test: Argument 'xmlReader' is not valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940360/effort-unit-test-argument-xmlreader-is-not-valid)

Comment: The way I understand it this shouldn't apply to 'Code First' mode, because I don't have an edmx to contain .ssdl, .csdl and .msl files to specify in my connection string metadata. I will continue my research into this tomorrow. Thank you so far.